Titus 1:2 and the Greek word αἰωνίων (aiōniōn)
I am having some trouble figuring this out, in Titus 1:2 the Greek word used for "eternal" in "eternal life" is: αἰωνίου (aiōniou) which means "perpetual" I think it can also mean "eternal/unending" as in Matthew 25:46. αἰωνίου (aiōniou) is also used in the last section of the same verse, to which I will ask a question about the last half only down below.
I recall online, reading from an article on Universalism (which I do not support) it says that BDAG (The Greek Lexicon) only has 3 definitions of "αἰωνίου (aiōniou) or "Aionios" which are:
"The adjective, it is claimed, means: (1) without beginning; or (2) without end; or (3) without beginning or end." (1)
(1) Source: https://www.concordant.org/expositions/the-eons/greek-words-aion-aionios/
So, in Titus 1:2, there is the phrase:
1.) before πρὸ(pro)  2.) time
χρόνων (chronōn)
3.) began
αἰωνίων (aiōniōn)
So the word began in Titus 1:2 seems to indicate from the Greek that it means "eternal" not "began".
Q: If BDAG lists only 3 options for Aionios/aiōniōn and they are the aforementioned options, shouldn't the translation say "before eternity past"?  or something to that effect?
Note: I do not currently possess a BDAG dictionary, and I have looked at BibleHub.com for more basic info.

Wouldn't "life - without end" and "before - time - without end" fit consistently? In both cases it means something that has a beginning but no end. The saved will gain life that never ends, and God existed even "before" time began. It's not obvious to me what you think the problem is with this verse.

@RayButterworth The Greek construction seems to imply "before time eternal" given the words used, and according to BDAG it seems that there is only 3 definitions or semantic usages involved within the word "Aionios", therefore, it would appear that "began" could potentially be an invalid use of the word Aionios, but as other commentators here have said, it seems that it is otherwise.  I clarified that in my post.  If you didn't initially see it, it's because of the seeming restriction placed from the BDAG semantic range for the word "Eternal".

"it's because of the seeming restriction placed from the BDAG semantic range for the word".  But one of those choices is "without beginning", and that meaning fits the two uses in this verse quite well.

@RayButterworth Ah, now it clicks, thank you.  That makes more sense.

The BDAG Greek Lexicon provides three primary definitions for αἰώνιος:

pert. to a long period of time, long ago

long ages ago Ro 16:25
πρὸ χρόνων αἰ. before time began 2 Ti 1:9; Tit 1:2 (in there last two pass. the prep. bears the semantic content of priority; on χρόνων αἰ.


pert. to a period of time without beginning or end, eternal of God

pert. to a period of unending duration, without end


Greek for reference:

ἐπ’ ἐλπίδι ζωῆς αἰωνίου, ἣν ἐπηγγείλατο ὁ ἀψευδὴς Θεὸς πρὸ χρόνων
αἰωνίων,


We see from the BDAG that in both Titus 1:2 and 2 Timothy 1:9, the phrase πρὸ χρόνων αἰωνίων (pro chronōn aiōniōn) is used. The preposition πρὸ (pro) means “before,” which indicates a priority in time. When combined with χρόνων αἰωνίων (chronōn aiōniōn), it stresses that something occurred before the ages or before eternal times.
In 2 Timothy 1:9, the phrase πρὸ χρόνων αἰωνίων is used to describe the grace given to us in Christ Jesus before time eternal. In other words, God’s grace and purpose was established before the creation of time.

For cross reference:
New King James Version translates it:

in hope of eternal life which God, who cannot lie, promised before
time began,

New International Version translates it:

in the hope of eternal life, which God, who does not lie, promised
before the beginning of time,

King James Version translates it:

In hope of eternal life, which God, that cannot lie, promised
before the world began;

English Standard Version translates it:

in hope of eternal life, which God, who never lies, promised before
the ages began[a]

ESV has a footnote that notes: Greek before times eternal
New American Standard Bible translates it:

in the hope of eternal life, which God, who cannot lie, promised
[a]long ages ago,

It also has a footnote that notes: Lit before eternal times

We can conclude that Paul’s use of αἰωνίων (aiōniōn) in these passages point to the eternal nature of God’s plan. That noted, the preposition πρὸ (pro) indicates a priority in time, implying that these actions and promises were established before the creation of time itself. So the phrase πρὸ χρόνων αἰωνίων can be understood as “before eternal times” or “before the ages began.” The priority is over the creation of time and the ages, meaning that God’s actions and promises are rooted in eternity.

Thank you for your answer, when you also mentioned at one point "eternal times" or "before eternal times" wouldn't that be a potentially contradictory statement in your view?  Other than that, solid answer, the last section was really helpful.

Thank you for clarification, what I mean is “eternal” and “times” are unending and temporal respectively, so you in theory cannot have an eternal time before time exists since the two concepts (time and eternity) are mutually exclusive concepts.  As in, God’s existence is eternal and static, but time is fluid and has a beginning point.  So “before the ages began” sounds more accurate, at least in English than “before eternal times”.

I see. πρὸ χρόνων αἰωνίων (pro chronōn aiōniōn) would indeed be contradictory if taken literally. It combines the concepts of eternity (timelessness) and times (temporal periods). However, the phrase is to be taken for what it's trying to convey not it's literal meaning. The idea is that of God’s actions and promises being established in the eternal realm. Which is why many translators use the word "began". Human language is inherently limited when it comes to describing eternal or infinite concepts. “before eternal times” uses temporal language to describe something that is beyond time.

I believe the focus is on the timelessness and pre-existence of God’s plan, rather than on a literal temporal sequence. I believe we should interpret such phrases in a non-literal sense to capture the intended meaning. Even if we simply said "before time began" we would be contradicting ourselves. The reason for that is that "before" implies a moment in time. So, we find it rather difficult to describe anything prior to time itself. It was difficult then the same as it's difficult now.

noted, thank you for the updated info.

Hermeneutics relies on several critical factors for interpretation. Off the top of my head, I’d include
•   Other specific scriptures – What other scriptures are relevant to the passage in question?
•   Context within the immediate scriptures – What is the subject and what are the other words being used in the passage?
•   Intellectual trajectory – What preparatory stages lead up to and what conclusions follow the passage in question?
•   Semantic range – What other writings use a specified word, how do they differ in context, and what’s the etymology of the specified word?
•   Linguistic analysis – What are the historical grammatical or idiomatic norms used?
•   Historical interpretations – what are the historical range of interpretations and references for a passage, including other major Bible translations and recently discovered manuscripts?
•   Opinions of experts – how do recognized experts and commentaries address the passage in question?
•   Archaeology – What recent archaeological discoveries impact an interpretation?
•   Logic - What logic is available to build or falsify a case for an interpretation?
Some of these can overlap, and I’m sure I’ve forgotten some other critical factors.
The word is derived from aión, SG 165 (similar to eon in English), which reports 165 occurrences in the New Testament.
In context, I looked up Titus 1 in the online Greek interlinear to confirm the word being used as aiōniou (SG 166):
https://biblehub.com/interlinear/titus/1.htm
Then, I looked up the word, αἰωνίων (aiōniōn) in my recently purchased BDAG (my wallet is still in shock) and found an entry under αἰώνιος (aiónios), which reads: “1. pert. To a long period of time, long ago . . . 2 Ti 1:9, Tit 1:2 (in these last pass., the prep. bears the semantic content of priority . . .”
Okay, but not entirely understanding “the preposition bears the semantic content of priority,” I looked at 2 Timothy 1:9 to get another example, where it reads in part

. . . and grace having been given us in Christ Jesus before time
eternal (aiōniōn) . . .
https://biblehub.com/interlinear/2_timothy/1.htm

Again, I would ask, "Priority over what or is this a form of emphasis?"
So, logically, I'd conclude that Paul would not have added the words "before time" in his letter to Timothy as a qualifier if aiōniōn wasn't a grammatically compatible word for eternity/eternal.
This context then raises the question of whether the "grace having been given us" should be interpreted corporately or individually, and whether Paul meant that this grace is applied specifically to the righteous saints of old, which is way beyond the scope of the question.
I hope this helps.

Hey Dieter, thanks for the input, I totally agree on the BDAG being a shock to your wallet, hence why I haven't snagged one yet.  However, I want to understand you correctly, are you implying that in the case of Titus 1:2 (not excluding the Timothy passage) that it may well mean "from a long time ago"?  I read everything you said, but I may not have gotten the meaning during my round of examining your answer.

Thanks @Cork88! So, here's how I look at it. Jesus died on the cross in atonement for all our sins. But this is like a pebble tossed into a pool--the waves extend not only into the future, but also into the past. This means that the faith of the Old Testament saints looked forward to atonement while the faith of the New Testament saints look backward to atonement. Thus, grace extends eternally in time, backward and forward. Any clearer?

That makes sense, and if that is the most probable answer for this verse then I will have to chew on it, thank you for this reference.  It does make sense if that can be put together, yes.

Titus 1:2 Promised before times eonian.
…> in expectation of life eonian, which God, Who does not lie, promises before times eonian.
“eonian life” does not refer to ‘eternity’ but to ‘eon’ (Gr. aion).

An eon in Scripture is a world age with both a beginning and an end. The idea that ‘eon’ as eternity should be opposed to time is nowhere more clearly refuted than in the expression we find here: “before times eonian ” (see also Rom.16:25 and 2Tim.1:9) .


There are times of days, months, years, but also of eons. And as we speak of daily, monthly, and annual times, so the Scripture speaks of “eonian times.” These times once began, for God “promised before eonian times”. “eonian times” also follow each other, because there are several “eonian times”. Scripture speaks “from eons ,” “the present eon,” and “the eons to come.” That is at least five eons.  Andrea Piet

There are not five eternitys so if you consistently translate the word eon to mean a period of time it takes away much confusion with that word.
Aion is the root word where
aiṓnios the cognate adjective.


aión ►
Strong's Concordance
aión: a space of time, an age
Original Word: αἰών, ῶνος, ὁ
Part of Speech: Noun, Masculine
Transliteration: aión
Phonetic Spelling: (ahee-ohn')
Definition: a space of time, an age
Usage: an age, a cycle (of time), especially of the present age as contrasted with the future age, and of one of a series of ages.


HELPS Word-studies

165 aiṓn (see also the cognate adjective, 166 /aiṓnios, "age-long") – properly, an age (era, "time-span"), characterized by a specific quality (type of existence).

We see in Titus 2:1  eoian life is promised  before time began.
When did the eons begin?
The answer is revealed in Hebrews 1:2
Scripture reveals that the eons were created in Christ Jesus.
Berean Literal Bible

in these last days has spoken to us in His Son , whom He appointed heir of all things, and through whom He made the ages, (aiṓn)

Literal Standard Version

in these last days speaks to us in [His] Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom He also made the ages;

So if age does not mean eternal then the question is if you you don't have eternal life, how do you live forever?
One is made immortal.
through Christ's life.
1 Corinthians 15:53-54

3For the perishable must be clothedf with the imperishable, and the mortal with immortality.
54When the perishable has been clothed with the imperishable and the mortal with immortality,g then the saying that is written will come to pass: “Death has been swallowed up in victory.”

Look at what it says about the coming ages, in Ephesians 2:7

that He might show, in the ages that are coming, the exceeding riches of His grace in kindness toward us in Christ Jesus,

Right now, we are living in the present, wicked eon.

… the Lord Jesus Christ, Who gives Himself for our sins, so that He might extricate us out of the present wicked eon, according to the will of our God and Father. Galatians 1:4


The “present wicked eon” is called “the eon of this world” in Ephesians 2:2.


The present eon is wicked because  the devil los is “the god of this eon” (2Cor.4:4).

One last quote regarding the eons to come.

"The expression “to the eons of the eons” is a well-known superlative from Hebrew. Similar to terms such as: the song of songs, the king of kings, the holy of holies, etc. “The eons of the eons” refer to the future superlative world ages. The reason for that is simple. After the “present wicked eon” (1:4), there are two world ages in which Christ will reign (Luke 1:33; Rev. 11:15). First in “the thousand years” and then in the still more superlative eon in which a heavenly Jerusalem will descend. In those two eons to come, GOD’S glory will be displayed.
In the current Bible translations the teaching of “God’s purpose of  the eons” (Eph.3:11) has been completely translated away. “The eons of the eons” are then made “for ever and ever”… But don’t let it be taken away from you – take Scripture as it presents itself!"
Andrea Piet


Do you think we have eternal life before we are made immortal?  1st John 5:13 makes it clear that we posses eternal life now, before the resurrection when we are made immortal, never to die again.

@Cork88 John makes it very clear that those believers had eonian life, because the life was in His Son who they believed in. They will not see it until they see Him and then they will become like Him. It will commence at their resurrection and last until death is no longer in action, at the consummation at the close of the eonian times.  John the apostle is dead right now, if he had everlasting life, he would still be living. Gentile believers at this time, also have an expectation of life as stated in Ephesians.

Eternal is something that has no beginning and no end and God alone falls into that category.  I totally understand that this is hard to grasp because so many of us have been taught that we have eternal life because of the translations that translate eon as eternal.

I can be wrong about a great many of things, but let’s look at the facts here.  John and Jesus said we posses eternal life now, the consummation is at the resurrection on the last day where our soul and body reunite, the bodily resurrection of Jesus is the model we all follow after, our flesh becomes incorruptible and immortal.  John 5:24 we pass from death into life after hearing Jesus’ word in this age.

John 5:24 says: “Most assuredly, I say to you, he who hears My word and believes in Him who sent Me has everlasting life, and shall not come into judgment, but has passed from death into life.“

@Cork88,  I appreciate the dialogue, and I learned a lot more about the word
166 aiṓnios (an adjective, derived from 165 /aiṓn ("an age, having a particular character and quality") – properly, "age-like" ("like-an-age"), i.e. an "age-characteristic" (the quality describing a particular age); It was helpful  to look at the 71 times it is used from the English concordance on Bible Hub.  I have much better understanding what that means regarding the quality of the particular age.  You are right that the believer has the Spirit of God and Christ living in Him now, passing from death into life.
